# PHP file partially fails with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to style a php file called dashboard.php with bootstrap. I only wrote some html code in the file to begin. When I test it, I found the styling in 'ul' tag was wrong. However other classes such as 'class="col-sm-2"' 'class="row"' are working as expect. 
This is code in the dashboard.php:

```
<?php ?>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
                        <li><a href="dashboard.php">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon--list-alt"></span>Add New Post</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manage Admins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Live Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- End of side area-->

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                </div><!-- End of main area-->
            </div><!-- End of raw-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the screen shot I made when testing the dashboard.php:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3sbQ.png)

If you chack the image. The left side with words in blue belongs to 'ul' tag. The style is completely wrong. It also failed to add glyphicon icons. I checked the syntax of my html code , there seems nothing wrong.

I also want to add more information:

1. the extension of the file is .php
2. I opened the XAMPP with Apache opened
3. the url that opens the file dashboard.php is correct:
   http://localhost/studyexample/PHPCMS/dashboard.php

Can you help me to find why the styling in 'ul' tag is completely wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: @Brian Gottier Do you mean that the bootstrap files could be corrupted? I had downloaded latest bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may be that you are using relative URLs for your assets, but have not used a base tag. The easiest thing to do is just add a forward slash to the path to your assets. When I run your code in CodePen it looks like it should:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpWLqo

So, what I mean is, for the following assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Add a forward slash so the URLs are absolute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Once you do that, I think you'll find that things start looking different for you. If not, you'll need to specify more of a complete path to the assets, meaning you may need to have the full path, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/studyexample/PHPCMS/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/studyexample/PHPCMS/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/studyexample/PHPCMS/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried all your suggestion, but they didn't solve the problem. I solved the problem by changing <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> into <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">